# Azure physical path

Tags: azure, path, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project hosted in Azure. I am trying to get the physical path of a file I store in App_Data folder. My code is as follows,

```
string databaseFile = "IPV6-COUNTRY.BIN"; 
string pathToDatabaseFile = "";                   
appRoot = HttpContext.Server.MapPath(@"~\");
pathToDatabaseFile = Path.Combine(appRoot, string.Format(@"App_Data\{0}", databaseFile));
```

This works fine in local environment but on Azure I get

```
pathToDatabaseFile = "D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\IPV6-COUNTRY.BIN"
```

which returns an "Error: Invalid Database Path." when I am trying to access the database.

Obviously I am missing something and I am wondering if someone could help.

Comment: how are you publishing your site?

Comment: if you mean how I publish it, I am doing it from inside Visual Studio.

Comment: Is this a Website or Web Role? How are you deploying the BIN file - as content bundled with the MVC site? Are there any licensing checks to use that database?

Comment: it is a website and the BIN file is stored in the App_Data folder as part of the MVC site. There is also a License.Key file stored in the same folder. The path of the License.Key file is declared with the same logic. As I have already mentioned when running the website locally it works fine and I am able to access the database and get results from a query.

Comment: and you also set the `Build Action` property of both `.BIN` and `.key` files to `Content` instead of `None` ?

Comment: and btw, you can just do `Server.MapPath("~/AppData/IPV6-COUNTRY.BIN")`

Comment: Build Action property of both .BIN and .Key files are already set to Content. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Server.MapPath("~/AppData/IPV6-COUNTRY.BIN") returns as a value  D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\IPV6-COUNTRY.BIN which is exactly the same with what I get from my code, which returns an "Error: Invalid Database Path." when I am trying to access the database.